# Dynamic button-C#

Tags: c#, windows, frontend

i have buttons this buttons for categories i want when click in this buttons i want to get rows from database products table and get two data product name and price and set it those values into dynamic buttons in windows application **notes i have set location properities for button such like flowLayoutPanel
i** have this code

```
private void btnhotdrink_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //int StartPositition = 100;
        //int EndPosition = 10;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt =clsprdcat.GET_HOTDRINK_CATEGORY();

        for(int i=0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int s=0; s < dt.Columns[4]; s++)
            {
                Button l = addbuttons(i,s);
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(l);
                //EndPosition +=70;
            }
        }
    }

    Button addbuttons(int i)
    {
        Button l = new Button();
        l.Name = "Name" + l.ToString();
        l.Text = "label" + l.ToString();
        l.ForeColor = Color.White;
        l.BackColor = Color.Green;
        l.Font = new Font("Serif", 24, FontStyle.Bold);
        l.Width = 170;
        l.Height = 80;
        //l.Location = new Point(start, end);
        l.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        l.Margin = new Padding(5);
        return l;
    }
```

**How Can i Do this**

Comment: You need to set the buttons' Location properties.

Comment: i have location properties also ill update my question thank you

Answer (score -1):

All Buttons are inherently dynamically created at runtime. The Windows Forms Designer works via partial classes: You work on one part. The designer on the other (designer.cs). And at compile time the Designers code is executed by calling "InitializeComponents()" in the Constructor. It can only do exactly the same things you can do.

If you need help with creating buttons yourself, you can always look into the Designer part. Just do take care not to change anything in that part. This System only works because the designer is exclusively writing in the file and compilation/loading of a Project is prone to seizing up if you did manual changes.

As you wrote it right now, this code will create `dt.Rows.Count` buttons at the same locaiton. Usually the Button creation code it needs access to the loop variable, to adapt the positions of each consequtive element.. Personally I prefer to leave positioning of Elements as much to automatics as possible. These designs simply adapt better to changes in resolution and window size.